# bindCallback emit only once

Tags: angular, rxjs

In Angular using RXJS have the following code in a class :

```
static on = (event: string, callback: (e: any) => void) => {
    switch (event) {
        case EVENTS.CONNECT.ALIAS:
            return emitter.subscribe(EVENTS.CONNECT.ALIAS, callback);
        case EVENTS.DISCONNECT.ALIAS:
            return emitter.subscribe(EVENTS.DISCONNECT.ALIAS, callback);
        case EVENTS.BUTTON_PRESS.ALIAS:
            return emitter.subscribe(EVENTS.BUTTON_PRESS.ALIAS, callback);
        case EVENTS.AXIS_MOVEMENT.ALIAS:
            return emitter.subscribe(EVENTS.AXIS_MOVEMENT.ALIAS, callback);
    }
}
```

which basically add the callback to list of callback for the specified eventListener. (the problem is not here)

In my Angular app, I have the following code in a service :

```
  addListener(eventName: string): Observable<GamepadEvent> {
    return bindCallback<string, GamepadEvent>(JoypadService.on)(eventName);
  }
```

And in a component I do :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.gamepadService.addListener(EVENTS.AXIS_MOVEMENT.ALIAS).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

The problem I face is that the subscription to the observable only fire once, but if I add the following line and do not use `bindCallback`:

```
 addListener(eventName: string): Observable<GamepadEvent> {
    JoypadService.on(eventName, (e) => console.log(e))
    return bindCallback<string, GamepadEvent>(JoypadService.on)(eventName).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)
    );
  }
```

this JoypadService.on(eventName, (e) => console.log(e))` will trigger all the time a change occur (as it should be).

Apparently bindCallback only fire once, but is it possible to make it fire infinitely until unsubscription ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the rxjs documentation of `bindCallback`

> Note that the Observable created by the output function will always
>   emit a single value and then complete immediately.

In the last version of your code you end up creating a new Observable any time you call `addListener(eventName: string)`. Any of these Observables will emit just once.

If you want to create an Observable that notifies many times until it is unsubscribed, you should probably look into the constructor of `Observable`.

In your case the code could look like this

```
createMyObs = (event: string): Observable<any> => {
    return new Observable(
        (observer: Observer<any>): TeardownLogic => {
            JoypadService.on(event, (e: any) => {
               observer.next(e)
            }
            // you can return here a function called upon unsubscription to
            // do any cleanup (i.e. the teardown logic)
        },
    );
};
```

This way you create one single Observable which represents a stream of events.

Comment: is there any api like fromEvent which watch for all events?